# Best method for putting code on hold for 'x' amount of hours

Tags: vb.net

I have an `If` statement that checks what day of the month it is

```
Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
   If currentDate.Day = 1 Then
      ''run code
   Else
      ''do nothing
   End If
```

I would like this code to run every 12 hours or so. What is the best method doing this minimising resource power? A timer would use up the most processing power and I have heard of using `sleep` and `wait` but unsure how to implement these solutions

Comment: Usually one doesn't _stop_ code.. instead using a cron job that triggers your code when needed at a specific time (as often as you want)

Comment: Have you considered using Windows Task Scheduler?